# using JNDI when websphere is shutdown

Tags: java, unit-testing, websphere, jndi

I am trying to test my we based project.I have created main method and its call some db related classes.Now the db related classes uses JNDI , so when running the code i get exception

Can i use JNDI when websphere server is stopped?If now how can i go about it?i dont want to run entire flow, i want to test my functionality by calling classes from main method

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Simple JNDI" for this.  Gives you a simple file based JNDI environment well suited for non-EE applications, or in situations where you do not want to occupy the network port.

http://www.osjava.org/simple-jndi/

Comment: This Simple JNDI project is not under active development anymore. There is a GitHub clone with bug fixes and some new features maintained by me. See https://github.com/h-thurow/Simple-JNDI .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use WebSphere's JNDI facilities when the server is in quiescing mode (shutting down).

I suspect something is a bit off with the way that you're testing your application. To help you, you'll have to provide us with more information about your architecture. Is it a standard servlet-JSP based WebApp that you're testing? What does your "main method" look like?

Isaac